# My code works Firefox, Safari and MS Edge but doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, push-notification, permissions, notifications

My code works Firefox, Safari and MS Edge but doesn't work in Chrome. (I try online my website. Doesn't work. is it possible my site ?)

**HTML**

```
<button onclick = "bildirim()" >Bildirim yolla</button>
```

**JS**

```
   function bildirim () {

   if (!("Notification" in window)) {
   alert("Your browser does not support Web Notifications API");
   } 

  else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {

  var notification = new Notification('Bildirim', {
  body: '', 
  icon: '',

  });
  setTimeout(function(){
  notification.close();
  }, 3000); 
  }

  else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {

  Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {

  if (permission === "granted") {
    var notification = new Notification('', {
      body: '', 
      icon: '',

    });
    setTimeout(function(){
notification.close();
}, 3000); 
   }
});
}
}
```

When I try offline, the button wants to open the permission. When I open it, it does not accept it and wants me to turn it back on. It keeps on going. Not send me notification.

When I upload html the web site, the button does not respond. The website does not even ask for permission. So I do not even get an error.

Chrome is up to date.

---

**SOLVED**

Chrome not working this code without SSL. So not work HTTP:// works HTTPS://.

Comment: Please include any error messages, or at least elaborate on "doesn't work". Also formatting your code properly will help people read it to find your issue.

Comment: Set your logging to "verbose" to see what Chrome is complaining about.

Comment: I add error and my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some observations regarding Notification in Chrome:

1. Notification doesn't work from local file (file://). If you have local webserver try putting it there and see it works or not. It worked for me.
2. When you have uploaded it on server, if its getting loaded in an iframe and the iframes domain is different than the main windows domain then it doesn't work if the domain of iframe is not already allowed for showing notification. For example: if you first check the example on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification, it doesn't work. But if you access the URL https://mdn.mozillademos.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification$samples/Example?revision=1326091 it asks for permission and once you allow, it works there as well as the previous link. Another example is https://davidwalsh.name/demo/notifications-api.php. Here it works because probably the iframe domain and top window domain are same.
3. I've seen working notifications on HTTPS sites only. I've not seen it from any HTTP site (except http://localhost). So that (HTTPS) could also be one of the requirements for notifications to work.

Unfortunately I've not found any links that document / confirm these observations.

Comment: I used the same code on my server. https://mdn.mozillademos.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification$samples/Example?revision=1326091 ... It doesnt work again my website. Button does not react. Don't ask me respond. I think the problem is related to Http. Did it work this code in your file:// or serves?

Comment: As mentioned above, it didn't work for file:// but did work for http://localhost. I've not tried uploading it to server.